# GMAIL imap_open invalid remote specification (errflg=2)

Tags: php, ssl, gmail-imap, imap-open

I'm trying to access gmail account messages by `imap_open`.

This is my code:

```
$mbox = imap_open ("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}", "gama.***@gmail.com", "password");
```

This is my php.ini:

> imap
>
> **IMAP c-Client Version**  2007f
>
> Kerberos Support    enabled
>
> openssl
>
> **OpenSSL support** :  enabled
> **OpenSSL Library Version**:OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
> **OpenSSL Header Version**: OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why but this worked for me

{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX